# Angular and Symfony2 - Different Templates for Search Engines

Tags: angularjs, symfony, seo, search-engine

I want to implement a Search-Tool with AngularJS on a Site in Symfony. The Angular-App is only part of this single Template. BUT the results of the search has also crawled from Search Engines as Google, Yahoo and so on. The Idea i have was to build a switch in a Action of Symfony. If the action detects that the request is from a Search Engine it gets a Template that have a regular search index with first results, without the angular-part.

The Question is, may this cause Problems?

Comment: maybe this is not the perfect thread but you should research a bit about in how far this is legal http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/440474.html , especially in europe there are "live-crawlings while generating a search result" a greyzone tending to illegality

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't do it like that.
You could put those important results in your sitemap with a higher priority.

Comment: Okay, there is a miss unterstanding :D The Results of the Search are not from Google or Yahoo, the Search Tool is for Content of the Website. The Problem is to get these Results indexed in Google because of the AngularJS Part.